# Is extending DOM elements via JavaScript still a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, html

This has been asked before, obviously, but I need some fresh information on the topic. I found a few articles and blog posts on the extension of DOM elements, and the most prominent arguments were browser incompatibilities. With IE11 doing surprisingly well.. is that even still an issue? Are there any other huge issues that prevent me from extending DOM elements directly, instead of through a wrapper?

Edit: To clarify, I'm talking about adding methods to DOM elements via existing JavaScript prototypes (most likely Element).

Comment: Are you referring to just extending properties or methods via their object prototype?

Comment: If this has been asked before, answers to the existing question should be improved or added, instead of intentionally spawning duplicates. Besides, this seems to be primarily opinion-based and/or too broad for SO format.

Answer (score 1):

> the most prominent arguments were browser incompatibilities

That might have been one argument, but not the most compelling, see [*What's wrong with extending the DOM*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). To summarise (more or less in order of importance):

1. Lack of specification
2. Host objects have no rules
3. Chance of collisions
4. Performance overhead
5. IE DOM is a mess
6. Browser bugs

That article is over 4 years old (April 2010) but not a lot has changed. Note that HTML5 is adding properties and methods to DOM objects at a steady pace so it's a moving target. Better to join the effort to improve the specification than head out on your own.

Comment: I don't see a precise problem in the lack of specification, as all major browsers do implement global Node, Element etc objects. The "no rules" thing and strange behavior resulting from it may be a thing, but could possibly be avoided. Same with collisions. Performance overhead in that article is about the performance overhead of manual element extension. IE DOM being a mess shouldn't apply to the latest version(s) anymore as far as I know. The browser bugs described in the article refers to old browsers, too.

Comment: If you're going to ignore IE10 and lower, then you just lost about 35% of desktop and some unknown percentage of mobile browsers (see [*netmarketshare:Desktop Browser Version Market Share*](http://netmarketshare.com)). Lack of specification means that whatever features you implement are likely going to behave differently to similar features that appear in the standard. I'd love to add an iterator to *Node*, but it just won't work in enough browsers and hopefully it will be implemented by browsers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally there is not a problem, as HTML5 expects to grow. Elements that do not exist today may exist in HTML6. The problem is elements which make sense to one person have no meaning to another and no meaning to search engines, etc.

Creating you own is discouraged as a "**Willful Violation**" of standards. Or in other words a bad idea, unless you have a really good idea and reason for doing it.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html

> 1.5.2 Compliance with other specifications
>
> This section is non-normative.
>
> This specification interacts with and relies on a wide variety of
>   other specifications. In certain circumstances, unfortunately,
>   conflicting needs have led to this specification violating the
>   requirements of these other specifications. Whenever this has
>   occurred, the transgressions have each been noted as a "willful
>   violation", and the reason for the violation has been noted.

Let me add some support for the blind depends on the software having a semantic understanding of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

With the new `data-` properties, there is now a fairly standardized way to extend DOM elements in a way that is both conflict free and doesn't create memory leaks.

```
var el = document.getElementById("my-gizmo");
el.setAttribute("data-notes", "Extra notes.");
var attr = el.getAttribute("data-notes");
el.removeAttribute("data-notes");
```

HTML5 offers a new `dataset` method to access these properties, but it has limited implementation and isn't ready for prime-time use.

It should be noted, for jQuery users, the *first* time you access a jQuery object's `data` method, it will read the `data-*` attributes, but it will not pick up any future changes.

With all of that said, access elemenets via expando properties, such as

```
el.extraProperty = "Blazzah!";
```

still has issues associated with it.

**Reference:** https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/10/using-data-attributes-in-javascript-and-css/

Comment: I think OP is referring to methods such as `Node.remove()` or other custom implementations on the element prototypes. Just how I read it though, your interpretation could be correct.

Comment: Ah, good catch @SmokeyPHP.  Yea, the way it is written could go either way.  I saw your request for clarification so we'll see how it goes.